# outputting multiple php search results to a different page?

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to output the search results in a different php page with an input and submit button.
It does work but it only displays one result at a time because theres only one placeholder for all the results, is there any way to output multiple relevant results and give each result its own placeholder?

for example i have three names in the database as follows, searching for `win10` should result in two results, but it only outputs the first one.

```
win7-haystack
win10-iceland
win10-road
```

heres the search php:

```
<?php
$arr = [];
$searchq = "%{$_POST['search-input']}%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT wallname FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE ?");
$stmt->execute([$searchq]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $arr[] = $row;
}
foreach($arr as $value){
    $val = implode('', $value);
    //echo ($val);
    //echo("<br><br>");
  }
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname = :val');
$stmt->bindParam(':val', $val);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $mlink = $row['mainlink'];
    $tlink = $row['thumbnail'];
    $dlink = $row['download'];
    $info = $row['info'];
  }
  /*echo ($mlink);
  echo("<br>");
  echo ($tlink);
  echo("<br>");
  echo ($dlink);
  echo("<br>");
  echo ($info);  */
  $final = ("<li><a href="."$mlink"."data-lightbox='wallpaper1'><img class='searchicon' src="."$tlink"."></a><span>"."$val"."</span><img class='searchbutton1 s1'
  src='/images/info.png'><a id='wall1.download' href="."$dlink"."><img class='searchbutton2' src='/images/download.png'></a>
<ul class='searchmenu menu1'>
  <p>"."$info"."</p>
</ul>
</li>");
?>
```

heres the result php:

```
    <form action= "" method= "post">
      <a href="#"><img id="glass" src="/images/search.png" type= "submit" 
    name="submit-search"></a><input id="search" name="search-input" 
    type="search" placeholder="Search By Name" autocomplete="off"><a 
    href="#"><img id="cancle" src="/images/cancle.png"></a>
   </form>
     <section id="result"><?php echo $final; ?></section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going through what should be the same set of query results twice, and both times throwing away everything except the values from the last iteration. Try something like this:

```
$arr = [];
$searchq = "%{$_POST['search-input']}%";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE ?');
$stmt->execute([$searchq]);
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $mlink = $row['mainlink'];
    $tlink = $row['thumbnail'];
    $dlink = $row['download'];
    $info = $row['info'];

    // Generate the desired per-row output, saving it in an array for later use.
    // Not clear what that should be, so this is a guess. Modify as needed.
    $arr[] = '<li>' . $mlink . '<br>' . $tlink . '<br>' . $dlink . '<br>' . $info . '</li>';
}

$final = '<ul>' . implode('', $arr) . '</ul>';
```